# Does an armorist need to pick "bound fang" more than once?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, spheres-of-power

So, a half-dragon [armorist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/spheres-of-power-classes-class-options/armorist/) wants a lots of claws as bound fangs. Since claws are OK natural attacks for a half-dragon's form, it passes. But does he need to pick the arsenal trick only once, or one time for each extra claw?

> [Bound Fang (Su)](http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/armorist)
>
> You may grow a natural weapon appropriate to your form. You may treat this natural weapon as a piece of bound equipment, using one of your instances of bound equipment. You may form and dismiss it as is usual for a bound or summoned weapon. You may form multiple natural weapons as bound weapons; each natural weapon occupies a piece of bound equipment. [...]

In addition to having to occupy a bound equipment slot for each extra natural attack.

---

Note:

Yeah, I noticed that Spheres of Power is 3pp. This is not the time or the place to bash 3pp material's quality.

Comment: @Draco18s Please don't use comments to write answers, even small or incomplete ones.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie even ones based on *pure assumption*?

Comment: @Draco18s Especially those.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, especially those. Consider: by putting an answer in a comment, you're pinning it to the top, above every other answer that has to earn the top spot through being quality + getting votes. That doesn't seem fair, does it? (There is more detailed explanations of this policy and its rationale in [the relevant FAQ on meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533).)

Comment: I'm not trying to "pin to the top," but whatever.

Comment: @Draco18s Fair enough, that explanation wasn't meant to say what your motive was, but it did come off that way. The main point is that it is an unfair maneuver for many reasons, regardless of the best intentions behind it.

Answer (score 3):

The page you linked does not contain the *Bound Fang* arsenal trick, but assuming that the quoted text is a complete and accurate copy from whatever the source you're using is:

### You only need to take the trick once

The effect of the *Bound Fang* arsenal trick is to give you a new option for what kind of equipment you can bind with the Armorist's Bound Equipment feature. It does not represent actually binding such a weapon, only the ability to do so - as the trick states, you may now grow a natural weapon which you can treat as a bound weapon with your Bound Equipment ability, and you can do so multiple times. The limit on doing so is the number of Bound Equipment slots you have available, not the number of arsenal tricks you can take.

Supporting this, as described by the Armorist's *arsenal trick* feature:

> Unless otherwise specified, an individual arsenal trick can only be gained once.

and tricks that can be taken more than once are always qualified with language like:

> You may gain this arsenal trick multiple times. Each time it is selected, [...]

The *Bound Fang* arsenal trick does not specify that it can be taken more than once, so it cannot be taken more than once, and it would not make sense for it to say you can grow multiple natural weapons if you were required to take the trick once for each natural weapon.

If I were your GM, though, I would argue that more than two claw attacks are not appropriate for a half-dragon's form, so you would only be able to manifest two natural claw weapons at once - no using Bound Equipment to stack up more than two natural claw attacks on a creature that only has two arms...

Comment: Those two starting arms already have claws, though. But the half-dragon was just an example. The trick is described in spheresofpower.wikidot.com  I didn't realize the d20pfsrd had not it.